# Unity: Cannot modify / add values to an array in System.Serializable

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a System.Serializable class

```
[System.Serializable]
public class _answersData
{
    public string word;
    public string wordmeaning;
    public string wordmeaning2;
    public GameObject result;    
}
```

I then have a monobehaviour class where an array of _answerData class is declared

```
public class gamePlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public _answersData[] answersData;
}
```

I am then trying to add data to _answerData array from another script using below method

```
public class challengeScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        gameplayScript = gameObject.GetComponent<gamePlay>();
        populate();
    }
    
    void populate()
    {
        answersCount = int.Parse(snapshot.Child("Answers").Child("Count").Value.ToString());
        gameplayScript.answersData = new _answersData[answersCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < answersCount; i++)
        {
            string positionNode = "Answer" + (i + 1).ToString();
            string _word = snapshot.Child("Answers").Child(positionNode).Child("Word").Value.ToString();
            gameplayScript.answersData[i].word = _word;   
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting NullReferenceException at 'gameplayScript.answersData[i].word = _word' line

Here's the error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Can someone guide what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it is `[Serializable]` doesn't mean the elements are automatically created once you create the array. By default all reference type elements will still be `null`.

Only within Unity the Inspector itself automatically creates instances of `[Serializable]` types and initializes the array itself.

In code you have to actually create your element instances yourself like e.g.

```
var answerData = new _answerData();
answerData.word = _word;
gameplayScript.answersData[i] = answerData;
```